# Javascript not working on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, muse

I'm using JavaScript to submit the current URL, all works fine until I enter to mobile screen, then the JavaScript appears to be gone, this is not only for "mobile" apparently the problem is based on the screen width.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#widgetu117_input" ).keyup(function( event ) {
       var getUrl = window.location;
       var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
    })
})
```

This is my code.
The form was build using muse (not my doing)

Comment: if it is based on screen width, there may be some other code prevent it. Without that code, we can't say anything

Comment: there is a space between getUrl and .protocol..

Comment: @Jry9972 The space does not matter.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be linked to your issue regarding you mentioning screen width etc. Have you tried to set up some test just to eliminate any other cause of error?

Comment: @cepharum ive tried everything i can think of but the problem persist be it on mobile or when i resize my screen on desktop, i know there must be a code to prevent it, how do i prevent a prevent?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it works for me. instead of using document ready, i changed everything to be a function and then, call it with settimeout at 7 seconds (tried with 3 but the problem persisted).

Hope nobody has this problem it was tricky to solve.